# How to properly use string::erase

Tags: c++, substring, erase

I'm not sure if I am using string::erase correctly. I am trying to make a function which would find a substring and erase it from the original string. I've already tested that string:find works but when it comes to erase, the same string is still there.

Source file .cpp

```
Sentence operator-(const Sentence& arg1, const Sentence& arg2)
{
    Sentence result = arg1;

    string str = arg1.get_sentence();
    string str2 = arg2.get_sentence();

    bool found = false;


    if (str2.find(str) != std::string::npos) {

        found = true;

    } else if (found == true) {

        str2.erase(str.find(str), str2.size());

    }


    return str2;

}
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the `else if` with just `if`? Does it work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

**First** you screwed up the `if` statement logic so that the erase statement was never executed (as pointed out in another answer).

**Second** you used [`std::string::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) incorrectly. The first argument should be the index of the first character to be removed and the second the total number of characters to be removed.

Since you already searched for the sub-string, you can re-cycle that information to be used with `erase`. A correct version of our code is therefore

```
auto pos = str.find(sub);
if(pos != std::string::npos)
    str.erase(pos,sub.size());
```

If you want to remove *all* occurrences of the sub-string, you could use a `for` loop:

```
for(auto pos=str.find(sub); pos!=std::string::npos; pos=str.find(sub))
    str.erase(pos,sub.size());
```

Comment: The last won't work -- if the substring is found, it will erase starting from 1 (the second character in the string), not from the point it was found at, because pos will be set to the result of the `!=` (so will be `true` which converts implicitly to 1), not to the position.

Comment: @ChrisDodd okay, I have edited that part away. One may do the same trick correctly using a `for()` statement – but is there a way with `if()`?

Comment: `if` and `for` are the same here -- you can have a declaration in the test, but the test must be by converting the declared thing to bool -- you can't also have a comparison.  Note that in a `for` you can also have a declaration in the init, so you likely don't need one in the test...

Comment: @ChrisDodd Well, in a `for()` you can have the definition of `pos` and the test separately, see answer.

Comment: @ChrisDodd  Thank you for the help. The code worked but instead of using "sub.size()", changing it to "sub.length()" gave the desired results.

Comment: @user76543 [`string::size()` and `string::length()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) both return the same thing. So this change makes no difference. Btw, if this post solved your problem, tou should accept it (click the tick underneath the answer score).

Answer (score 0):

If we rewrite

```
if (str2.find(str) != std::string::npos) {
    found = true;
} else if (found == true) {
    str2.erase(str.find(str), str2.size());
}
```

to something like how the compiler parses it, it would be something like

```
if (str2.find(str) != std::string::npos) {
    found = true;
} else {
    if (found == true) {
        str2.erase(str.find(str), str2.size());
    }
}
```

Now it's quite easy to see that the condition in the `else` branch is never going to be true. If the `else` branch happens, then the other branch could never have happened and `found` will still be `false`.

With the code you show, you could just have skipped the `found` variable, and just do

```
if (str2.find(str) != std::string::npos) {
    str2.erase(str.find(str), str2.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to erase all same substring from the original string.This may work.

```
    while(str2.find(str) != std::string::npos) { 
        str2.erase(str2.find(str), str2.size());//here 
    }
    return str2;//you shouldn't return string, it's not your return type.

str.erase (pos,length); //your choice
//if str="abcdefg"
str.erase(3,2);
//str="abcfg"
```

or

```
 str.erase (first,last);
    //if str="abcdefg"
    str.erase(str.begin()+3,str.begin()+5);
    //str="abcfg"
```

if str2 is a substring of str, "str.find(str2);" will return the first position where it first appeared.

```
str="Thank you";
str2="you";
str.find(str2);//return 6
```

so

```
 str2.erase(str.find(str), str2.size());
```

should be

```
 str2.erase(str2.find(str), str2.size());
```

Hope that will help.